# Django, access html form field value sent from JQuery AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-views

forms:

```
class TransactionForm(forms.ModelForm):     
    CHOICES = ((1, 'Buy'), (2, 'Sell'),)

    coin = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = Coin.objects.all()) 
    buysell = forms.ChoiceField(choices = CHOICES)

    field_order = ['buysell', 'coin', 'amount', 'trade_price']

    class Meta:
        model = Transaction
        fields = {'buysell', 'coin', 'amount', 'trade_price'}

    def __init__(self, coin_price = None, user = None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TransactionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print("Transaction form init: ", user, coin_price)

        if user:
            self.user = user
            qs_coin = Portfolio.objects.filter(user = self.user).values('coin').distinct()
            print("qs_coin test: {}".format(qs_coin))
            self.fields['coin'].queryset = qs_coin

        if coin_price:
            print("coin price test")
            self.coin_price = coin_price
            self.fields['price'] = self.coin_price
```

jquery snippet:

```
    $('#id_buysell').on('change', function(){

            console.log("buysell");
            console.log($('#id_buysell').val());

            var $formData = $(this).attr("id_buysell");
            console.log($formData.val());

            $.ajax({
                method: "GET",
                url: "/myportfolio/add_transaction",
                data: $formData,
            });

        });

    $('#id_coin').on('change', function(){

        console.log("coin change")

        var $formData = $(this).attr("id_coin");
        console.log($formData.val());

        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "/myportfolio/add_transaction",
            data: $formData,
        });

    });
```

views snippet

```
def add_transaction(request):
    print(request.method)
    print("test1")

    print(request.GET)

    if request.method == "GET":
        if request.is_ajax():
            print("ajax test")

            data = {
                'test': "test1"
            }

            form = TransactionForm(user = request.user, coin_price = GetCoin("Bitcoin").price)

            return JsonResponse(data)
```

In my jquery functions I declare

> var $formData = $(this).attr("id_coin");

and then pass it to the view with GET. However I'm not sure how to actually get this data in my view.

So how can I access this value? If I wanted to print it to see this value could I do something like this or similar?:

> print(request.GET['coin'])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't send data that way via ajax, you need to send it like the following
`{key:'value',key2:'value2'}`

```
var coin = $(this).attr("id_coin");

$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "/myportfolio/add_transaction",
    data: {
        id_coin:coin // retrrieve the value in python with the key
    },
});
```

In your views:

```
print(request.GET.get('coin'))
>>> # The value of coin from JS ajax
```